# Problema con la configuración del tamaño y la posición del navbar

Tags: css, html5, vue.js, navbar, nav

He estado trabajando un proyecto en vue / code pen, sin embargo tengo un problema con la configuración del tamaño del navbar; la idea es que tenga el largo de la pagina y poder organizar los componentes.

https://codepen.io/rickbm400/pen/KKQwrXj

Aquí el codepen del código.

Comment: Debes agregar aquí tu código HTML y CSS con respecto al nabvar. Y al parecer tu nabvar no tiene casi nada de estilo en CSS. Debes trabajar en su estilo

Comment: El código debe ir _en la pregunta_. Si el enlace llega a caer, el contenido esencial de la pregunta se perderá. Además, especifica en el título _cuál es el problema_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Asi lo arregle

```
 body {
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f7f8fc;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    color: #10182f;
}

.input {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.login {
    background: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué hace este código? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta: recuerda que [es.so] _no es un servicio de código_. Lee [answer].